# Find match pattern and delete the first occurrence

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file1

```
NR2SKRD12BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.A1(n7),.A2(),.ZN(n8)); |2
MUX2D2BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.I0(n8),.I1(),.S(),.Z(n9)); |4
CKLHQD16BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.CPN(#),.E(1),.TE(n9),.Q(n10)); |5
LHCSNQD1BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.CDN(n10),.D(),.E(1),.SDN(),.Q(n11)); |6
OAI21D8BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.A1(n11),.A2(),.B(),.ZN(n12)); |9
DCCKND16BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.I(n12),.ZN(n13)); |10
INVSKFD14BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.I(n13),.ZN(n14)); |11
NR2SKRD12BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.A1(n7),.A2(n1),.ZN(n8)); |2
MUX2D2BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.I0(n8),.I1(n2),.S(),.Z(n9)); |4
```

I need to find matching lines in file1 i.e 1st field. Field are seperated by`-` and if match found , delete 1st match line.

I want output as

```
CKLHQD16BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.CPN(#),.E(1),.TE(n9),.Q(n10)); |5
LHCSNQD1BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.CDN(n10),.D(),.E(1),.SDN(),.Q(n11)); |6
OAI21D8BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.A1(n11),.A2(),.B(),.ZN(n12)); |9
DCCKND16BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.I(n12),.ZN(n13)); |10
INVSKFD14BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.I(n13),.ZN(n14)); |11
NR2SKRD12BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.A1(n7),.A2(n1),.ZN(n8)); |2
MUX2D2BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.I0(n8),.I1(n2),.S(),.Z(n9)); |4
```

Here `NR2SKRD12BWP210H6P51CNODSVT` and`MUX2D2BWP210H6P51CNODSVT` have same $1. So delete their 1st match line.

I tried the code

```
awk -F'-' 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next} !(($1) in a)' file1
```

But this code is to find match and delete lines between two files. How can I find match and delete for single file.
*delete the first match line only. Keep the second,third, fourth etc repeats.

Comment: What is your logic behind `FNR==NR` when dealing with one just file?

Comment: Delete first occurrence .only  If there are third fourth repeats then keep them. @rowboat

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{ FS="-" }
FNR==NR{
  arr[$1]++
  next
}
arr[$1]>1 && ++arrAgain[$1]==1{ next }
1
' Input_file Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                             ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{ FS="-" }                   ##Setting field separator as dash here.
FNR==NR{                          ##Checking FNR==NR condition which will be TRUE when 1st time Input_file is being read.
  arr[$1]++                       ##Creating array arr with 1st field index and keep increasing its value with 1 on each of its occurrence.
  next                            ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
arr[$1]>1 && ++arrAgain[$1]==1{   ##Checking if arr value with 1st field index is greater than 1 and its first time occurring in arrAgain then skip that line.
  next                            ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
1                                 ##1 will print current line.
' Input_file Input_file           ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 'H;x;s/^(\n[^-]*-)[^\n]*(.*\1)/\2/;x;$!d;x;s/.//' file
```

Make a copy of the current line in the hold space.

If the current key already exists in the hold space, remove the first line.

At the end of the file, swap to the hold space, remove the first newline that was introduced when making copies and print the results.

Answer (score 1):

another `awk`

```
$ awk -F- 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++; next} !(--a[$1])' file{,}

CKLHQD16BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.CPN(#),.E(1),.TE(n9),.Q(n10)); |5
LHCSNQD1BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.CDN(n10),.D(),.E(1),.SDN(),.Q(n11)); |6
OAI21D8BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.A1(n11),.A2(),.B(),.ZN(n12)); |9
DCCKND16BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.I(n12),.ZN(n13)); |10
INVSKFD14BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.I(n13),.ZN(n14)); |11
NR2SKRD12BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.A1(n7),.A2(n1),.ZN(n8)); |2
MUX2D2BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.I0(n8),.I1(n2),.S(),.Z(n9)); |4
```

double scan file, first round count the occurrences of each key, second round print the last one only.

Answer (score 1):

To delete first duplicate:

```
awk -F- 'NR==FNR {++a[$1]; next} a[$1]==1; {a[$1]=1}' file file
```

Read same file twice. Count $1 on the first read, decide what to do with the count on the next.